# How can I use joint primary keys and Kohana 3 ORM?

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `requests` (
  `ctrc_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`ctrc_id`),
  KEY `fk_requests_users1` (`user_id`)
)
```

What I have to change in the model? Will ko3 ORM work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kohana doesn't support compound primary keys. Take a look at the [Search results for 'compound'](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/search?Search=compound) on the Kohana forum to see if someone has solved this problem before.

You should also keep an eye on this issue for any signs of progress: [Multi primary keys / foreign keys in ORM](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/3413). It wont harm to add your support for the feature either.